# memory leakage in system libraries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

below is my memory leakeage . i cant identify were its leaking but 6 leakage is there. ***in grouping column when hide my system libraries i checked means below leakeage is not showing.***( in image lefthand side bottom u een this grouping column). problem is my sytem libraries or something else.

[image]

i already wasted 2 days so only am asking here. help in this.

Were is leakege?

Comment: can you expand symbol name and paste what's there?

Comment: @Johnny Grass, i update my image with expanded.  @  trojanfoe  , what kind of information you needed. am asking question about why its happening were its leakage, if in grouping column when hide my system libraries i checked means below leakeage is not showing.( in image lefthand side bottom u een this grouping column). problem is my sytem libraries or something else.

Comment: Have you tried "build and analyze"? It may help track down your bugs.

Comment: @trojanfoe normally I agree 100% that you need to post the code where the leak might be, but in this case the stack trace in the leaks report is all in system libraries

Comment: http://support.openfeint.com/general/llvm-compatibility-prior-to-of-sdk-2-9-for-ios/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can gather from the image, there seems to be some kind of background thread running constantly...be it a system library or some object which is not properly released. Such issues really are a bottleneck in development. It becomes really complex to find out the exact point where the leak is occurring.

Build and Analise is a good option, since it will give you a proper path as to where and why the leak is occurring!!

Best of luck!!

Answer (score 4):

### Is the problem in my system libraries, or something else?

(Highlighting OP's question, since whoever thinks this needs to be closed didn't see it.  Perfectly valid question.)

The leaks appear to be entirely in the system;  it is possible for such a leak to be caused by your code indirectly, but it is extremely unlikely.

It could also be a false positive;  the system is playing games with a pointer such that a reference does still exist.

In any case, file a bug via http://bugreport.apple.com/.

If you don't see growth over time -- if the leak is limited to 6 ~32 byte allocations for the runtime of your app -- then it isn't something to worry about beyond the annoyance of being there.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the call stack in the screenshot, it looks like all the calls are inside system libraries, running on a background thread. libGLProgrammability.dylib is probably OpenGL, which appears to be running LLVM internally.

Does the leak grow over time? If not, since there are only 6 objects (total 192 bytes) showing as leaked you probably don't want to make yourself too crazy about this...

Answer (score 0):

You need to alloc and release all object correctly, that is not easy, but necessary.

You can enable another control from build options: `RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER` to show all wrong release at compile time

See this answer: [iPad View Controller Memory Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483125/ipad-view-controller-memory-management/4483567#4483567)

hope this helps.
A

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this on the device?  Sometimes you can see leaks in the simulator that do not show up on the device.