# CCsprite.m am getting analyser error in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

When am using build and analyse method the following error occurs:- `/Users/ghost/demo/libs/cocos2d/CCSprite.m:476:2 Assigned value is garbage or undefined`

in:- `-(void)updateTransform` method am getting above error

here is my screenshot for this error:- 
[image]
Is it my fault that the program is leaking memory or in cocos2d libraries leaking memory.

recently i asked question regarding this same issue refer the link :-
[memory leakage in system libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863977/memory-leakage-in-system-libraries)

how to rectify this  issue:-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assigned value is garbage or undefined

None of that indicates anything about leaking memory.  The analyzer checks for much more than just memory abuse.

The analyzer has identified a code path that, if followed, will lead to an undefined/uninitialized value being used.   May happen, may not, but it is worthy of a bug against cocos2d!

Comment: can u see the linked for another question. in that i shown screenshot of leaking memory.   i dont know were its leaking. ( either my fault or libraries fault) can u help me regarding this issue

Comment: ya i know. i registered in bugreporter.apple also. but they didnt reply still. and this answer is unclear can u explain in detail.......

Comment: bugreporter.apple.com is a bug reporting conduit;  you've let Apple know about the issue you have potentially identified and, if it is an issue, it'll be fixed in some future release of the software.  Don't expect feedback through that channel. If it is of great enough concern to you, go for a dev tech incident.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem in the Cocos code. The matrix is initialized in two conditionals, therefore it might not be initialized before it’s used. The conditionals might be written so that the matrix is *always* initialized, the analyzer does not know. I’d simply initialize the matrix with identity transform, that certainly does not hurt. And yes, bbum is right, this is worthy of a bug report – no library should throw analyzer results unless there’s no other way.